# Matlab - Retrieving single cell from file-loaded array for use in function

Tags: matlab

XTrain is a vector of float elements loaded from a file. The script then executes a function to utilize the file contents.

An excerpt of the file elements is

- 128.3000
- 127.4700
- 127.8800

I can retrieve a single cell value using the command-line code XTrain(1,1)

The following is my function which is resulting in an error if i switch the comments on the test lines:

```
    function loss = LS(XTrain)

      a = [1 2 3 4] 

      for i=1:150,
        %test = XTrain(1,1)
        test = a(1,1)
      end
      loss = test;
    end
```

Here is the error:

Error using Func (line 6)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in run (line 64)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);

Error in Load (line 12)
run Func

Is the problem due to the float type of the file data?

File Data
1   65.78   112.99
2   71.52   136.49
3   69.40   153.03
4   68.22   142.34

Script File:

```
DATA = dlmread('xtraindata.txt')
XTrain = DATA(1:150,2:2)
run Func
```

Func File:

```
function lret = Func(XTrain)
lret = XTrain(1,1)
end
```

Comment: MATLAB seems to think that XTrain is a function. are you sure that you're passing in a vector?

Comment: I ran the code you provided and even if you don't pass XTrain to LS(), there are no errors. There is an error only if you uncomment line 6. If you do uncomment it, then as MrAzzaman mentioned, you have to pass a parameter.

Comment: I'm loading the XTrain data from a file using the following code executed in a script which then calls the function LS.
DATA = dlmread('xtraindata.txt')
XTrain = DATA(1:150,2:2) % I only want to load all the float-values from the second column

Comment: Can you put the full code in your post? Or at least the important parts of the script file? It might help us to determine what's going on.

Comment: I've edited the question providing full contents of script and function file. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

```
run Func
```

by

```
lret=Func(XTrain)
```

If you defined Func in Func.m, and "run Func" was NOT in Func.m, you may alternatively delete the line

```
function lret = Func(XTrain)
```